# MPICH's MPI_Comm_dup() fails inside copy constructor

Tags: c++, mpi, mpich

**I have an object that need to design a copy constructor for it.
The object has an MPI_Comm member which should be copied to the new object.
I do not want to use a shallow copy since right way is to duplicate the communicator.**

```
myClass::myCLass(const myClass& in_class)
{
// 
....
MPI_Comm_dup(inclass.comm, &myclass.comm);
...
}
```

It compiles fine with MPICH but crashes at runtime with the following error
**( " Assertion failed in file src/mpi/topo/topoutil.c at line 101: n == 0" )** 
other implementations such as intel work fine.

Answer (score 0):

With so little information one can only guess. If it is the `n` in `topoutil.c` http://formalverification.cs.utah.edu/sawaya/html/db/d9e/topoutil_8c-source.html , it sounds a lot like you are trying to duplicate a null (empty?) communicator.

Add your own `assert(inclass.comm != MPI_COMM_NULL)` before the call.

Comment: That is not the case, as I mentioned both intel and openmpi works meaning that they produce correct results!

Comment: @Hasbestein it can work by chance in other implementations that do not have this check or were not compiled with debug flags. Please post a minimal working code. And finally it would help if you post or link to the version of topoutil.c or even the mpich version that you are using.

Comment: Unfortunate;ly this is a part of a much bigger commercial code and hence I can not post it. mpich/3.2.1 is the version that I am using. I am duplicating a non null communicator, In fact the communicator is a Distributed graph communicator. Other implementation work with debug as well as release flags.

Comment: @Hasbestein what makes you think that being inside the constructor produces the error. Can you reproduce the problem outside a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this issue still affects MPICH 3.4.2 and the only work-around I have found so far is to recreate another version of the topology-aware communicator instead of duplicating it.

Comment: [Submitted as bug report 5628](https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/issues/5628)